# С последними 2 версиями jquery - 3.3.1 и 3.4.0 сообщения всплывают не под полем формы, а в левом верхнем углу экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма, при неправильном вводе в поле под этим полем всплывает сообщение об ошибке или информационное.

Используется  **jquery** и **notify**. Все это работает правильно вплоть **до 3.2.1 версии jquery включительно**.

С последними 2 версиями **jquery - 3.3.1 и 3.4.0** сообщения всплывают не под полем формы, а в левом верхнем углу экрана.

Ниже форма с jquery - 3.3.1 для демонстрации проблемы. Если переключить на 3.2.1, проблемы нет.

```js
/* Проверка поля Имя на соответствие длинны */
$("#name").keyup(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value.length > 24 || value.length < 2){ 
    $(this).notify("От 2 до 25 символов", "info");
    $(this).val(value.slice(0,24));
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

form {
  display:block;
  width:450px;
  height:auto;
  margin:50px auto;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:15px;
  background-color:rgb(84, 84, 84);
  font-size:16px;
  font-family:'Arial';
  color:rgb(255, 255, 255)
}

table {
  margin:0 auto;
}

table td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

table td.lbl {
  padding-top:12px;
}

#title {
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  color:rgb(0, 184, 246);
}

.textbox {
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  margin-left:10px;
  padding:10px;
  border:none;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-color:rgb(190, 190, 190);
  font-size:16px;
  color:rgb(63, 63, 63);
}

.errtextbox {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(255,0,0);
}

.help {
  width:190px;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:25px;
  padding-left:25px;
  font-size:12px;
  color:rgb(140, 140, 140);
}

#info {
  height:100px;
  resize:none;
}

#send {
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto 10px;
  padding:7px;
  border:none;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:rgb(0, 128, 174);
  font-size:16px;
  color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script-->
  
<script src="https://rawgit.com/notifyjs/notifyjs/master/dist/notify.js"></script>
  
<form action="/reg" method="POST" id="regForm">
  <lable id="title">Запрос на регистрацию</lable>
  <table>
    <tboby>
      <tr>
        <td class="lbl">Имя:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="textbox"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><lable class="help">От 2 до 25 символов</lable></td>
      </tr>      
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="button" id="send" value="Отправить заявку"/>
</form>
```

Comment: когда на пустой форме жму кнопку, подсказка появляется внизу кнопке на всех версиях jquery

Comment: на кнопке да, появляется под кнопкой, а в полях - появляется в левом верхнем углу

Comment: вы сделайте свой пример кода минимальным. чтобы сразу было ясно, что и как. я попробовал указать  не валидный email, а сообщение все равно у кнопки показывается. никто тут не захочет разбирать код, чтобы понять, что надо ввести в форму для нужного эффекта.

Comment: https://github.com/jpillora/notifyjs/issues/97 тикет  на гитхабе есть по этому поводу.

Comment: teran, благодарю что отредактировал (минимизировал) код, я не знал что так надо. В первый раз задал вопрос и мне написали, и прочитал в правилах, что нужно все выкладывать, вот и выложил, теперь буду знать как надо. Ветка на github умерла в июне 2017